# AWS EC2 auto-scaling Windows server: how to set the hostname ("computername")?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, autoscaling, aws-ec2

I have an elaborate framework for autoscaling UNIX servers to configure their hostname with a script on launch (startup) using an NFS (EFS) where they look up what their hostname should be, then set hostname and move on.

When trying to do the same for Windows servers, I am stuck with the problem that changing the "computername" on Windows requires reboot. As soon as I reboot an autoscaled instance, however, it will be terminated and another one shows up in its place.

What can I do to fix this?

Can I somehow ask the autoscaling manager for lenience, allowing a reboot once without terminating the instance?

Can I at least tell the autoscaler to run some script or call or lambda or whatever execute some logic to determine the hostname setting to use before launching the instance?